# I'm trying to make a delay before the answer of who won and who lost pops up(Rock paper scissors game)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to make my game more realistic but I do not know how or where to use the setTimeout/setInterval method and I do not know what else to try.

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            rockPaperScissorsComputer: ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'],
            rockPaperScissorsUser: null,
            random: null
        };
        this.handleClickRock = this.handleClickRock.bind(this);
        this.handleClickPaper = this.handleClickPaper.bind(this);
        this.handleClickScissors = this.handleClickScissors.bind(this);
    }
    handleClickRock() {
        const min = 0;
        const max = 3;
        const random = min + (Math.random() * (max - min));
        this.setState({ random })
        this.setState({
            rockPaperScissorsUser: 'Rock'
        })
    }
    handleClickPaper() {
        const min = 0;
        const max = 3;
        const random = min + (Math.random() * (max - min));
        this.setState({ random })
        this.setState({
            rockPaperScissorsUser: 'Paper'
        })
    }
    handleClickScissors() {
        const min = 0;
        const max = 3;
        const random = min + (Math.random() * (max - min));
        this.setState({ random })
        this.setState({
            rockPaperScissorsUser: 'Scissors'
        })
        function after() {
            document.getElementsByClassName('x')
        }
        setInterval(after, 1500)
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button value="Click me!" onClick= 
 {this.handleClickRock}>Rock</button>
                <button value="Click me!" onClick={this.handleClickPaper}>Paper</button>
                <button value="Click me!" onClick={this.handleClickScissors}>Scissors</button>
    enter code here

                <h2 className="x">You selected: 
{this.state.rockPaperScissorsUser}</h2>
                <h1 className='x'>The computer selected: {this.state.rockPaperScissorsComputer[Math.floor(this.state.random)]}</h1>



                {

         this.state.rockPaperScissorsComputer[Math.floor(this.state.random)] 
           ===
                        this.state.rockPaperScissorsUser ? <h1> It was a tie 
          </h1> :
                        this.state.rockPaperScissorsUser ===
                            'Rock' && Math.floor(this.state.random) == 2
                            || this.state.rockPaperScissorsUser === 'Paper' &&
                            Math.floor(this.state.random) === 0 ||
                            this.state.rockPaperScissorsUser == 'Scissors' &&
                            Math.floor(this.state.random) === 1
                            ? <h1 className="ribbon">You Win</h1> : <h1>The computer wins</h1>

                }


            </div>
        );


    }
```

It should pause, I think before it shows the winner but it does not. I have tried putting in a setInterval button but it does not work. I am trying to make the delay around one second and for the game to show the results after the one second is finished.

Comment: well ... your setInterval calls `after` which gets an element ... how is that displaying anything? P.S. I'd use setTimeout not setInterval because it makes more sense to

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: use setTimeout to call a function that displays what you want it to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think moving the outcome message of the game from the render method to state makes the most sense for giving the perception of calculation time.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    rockPaperScissorsComputer: ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'],
    rockPaperScissorsUser: null,
    random: null,
    outcome: '' // new state for containing the outcome message
  };
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

As well, combining the three click handlers into one makes using a setTimeout just once in the handler less redundant than three times.

This function sets the outcome to '', calculates the outcome and the outcome message, then 1000 milliseconds later, sets the outcome state.

```
  handleClick(type) {
    this.setState({outcome: ''}, () => {
      const min = 0;
      const max = 3;
      const random = Math.floor(min + (Math.random() * (max - min)));
      this.setState({ random })
      this.setState({
        rockPaperScissorsUser: type
      })
      const tie = (this.state.rockPaperScissorsComputer[random] === type);
      const win = (
         ((type === 'Rock') && (random === 2)) || 
         ((type === 'Paper') && (random === 0)) || 
         ((type === 'Scissors') && (random === 1))
       );
      setTimeout(() => {
        // Important part here. This occurs after the 2 parameter to setTimeout (1000 milliseconds)
        this.setState({outcome: (
          <h1 className={win && 'ribbon'}>{
            tie ? 'It was a tie' : 
              win ? 'You win' : 'The computer wins'
          }</h1>
        })
      }, 1000)
    })
  }
```

Now your render looks like:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
       <button value="Click me!" onClick={() => this.handleClick('Rock')}>Rock</button>
       <button value="Click me!" onClick={() => this.handleClick('Paper')}>Paper</button>
       <button value="Click me!" onClick={() => this.handleClick('Scissors')}>Scissors</button>
       enter code here

       <h2 className="x">You selected: {this.state.rockPaperScissorsUser}</h2>
       <h1 className='x'>The computer selected: {this.state.rockPaperScissorsComputer[Math.floor(this.state.random)]}</h1>

      {this.state.outcome}
    </div>
  );
}
```